Looking for a movie where people had to plug a cord or pipe on their necks to survive
I can't recall anything else from this movie but this scene with a man and a woman trying not get caught, they enter an abandoned house where there were something like pipes or cords attached to the wall and they had to plug this on their neck to stay alive. I believe it was some kind of an antidote they had to receive every few hours. i don't recall aliens, space ect. Not Mindwarp, eXistenZ or Matrix.

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I'm going to throw this out there as it sounds similar (But not exact)
Vile (2011)

A group of friends stop to pick up a hitchhiking woman only to end up
  getting drugged by her with a gas. They awaken to find that vials have
  been implanted in the base of their skulls - which are of course
  instantly fatal if they are removed, a grinning professional looking
  woman informs them on TV screens that they have 22hrs to fill these
  vials with a specific amount of brain fluid, a fluid that is produced
  during times of extreme pain. Along with another group of unlucky test
  subjects and with time ticking away they decide to work together and
  share the burden of reaching their painful target.


Thank you very much for your answer but it's not that unfortunately.

Any feedback from the mystery down voter?

it wasn't me mate

Some people just don't like ID questions...
